# Selecting all rows but those within a range of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix and I want to iterate over chunks of it.  Each iteration I want to grab that chunk and everything NOT in that chunk.  For example

```
#grab all rows between index1 and index2
chunk = arr[index1:index2, :]

#want to grab the rest of the matrix that wasn't already grabbed in chunk
#this is the wrong syntax but demonstrates the behavior I'm looking for
rest = arr[ not(index1:index2), :]
```

Any good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to `vstack` the 2 pieces:

```
In [68]: arr
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
       [ 1,  6, 11, 16],
       [ 2,  7, 12, 17],
       [ 3,  8, 13, 18],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19]])

In [69]: arr[2:4,:]
Out[69]: 
array([[ 2,  7, 12, 17],
       [ 3,  8, 13, 18]])

In [70]: np.vstack([arr[:2,:],arr[4:,:]])
Out[70]: 
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
       [ 1,  6, 11, 16],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19]])
```

Or you could construct a discontinuous list of indices, e.g. `[0,1,4]`

```
arr[[0,1,4],:]
```

In `np.lib.index_tricks` there is a function (class actually) that streamlines constructing such a list (from lists or slices):

```
np.r_[:2,4:5]  # == np.array([0,1,4])
```

In fact `r_` can be used like `vstack`:

```
np.r_[arr[:2,:],arr[4:,:]]
```

Often you want to divide an array based on some condition, in which case a boolean index is useful:

```
I=np.ones(5,dtype=bool)
I[2:4]=False   # array True, with False for the rows to omit
arr[I,:]
arr[~I,:] # the original slice
```

Answer (score -1):

if you know you don't want index1:index2.. why not just do this ?

```
rest=arr[index3:]
```

Comment: Well first off this solution assumes that the chunk that I grabbed originally starts at the beginning of the matrix.  To your point however I suppose I could do something like `rest = arr[:index1] + arr[index2:]`...which may be the best solution.  Was just wondering if there was an even more concise way

Comment: I think that might your best bet . I would be curious to see if there's a better way :)